# creating column family in cassandra for CDR analysis

Tags: cassandra

I am new to cassandra, using cql3. I want to store call detail records data ( e.g, mobile              OtherParty_number, call_Type, Start_Time, End_Time, IMEI, IMSI, etc.) 
which can answer queries like,

between 1st Apr'12 to 20 Sep'12 
        (a) who only call to others? 
        (b)who only received the calls? 
        (c) who only send SMS?

Comment: it will depend... include your thought how you want to store your data??

Answer (score 1):

it's defiantly doable, you will need to make sure that you get your column family keys right, and add secondary index if needed. bear in mind that C* handle relatively well large rows. Have a read for netflix tech blog http://techblog.netflix.com/search/label/Cassandra and ebay tech blog as good introduction  http://www.ebaytechblog.com/2012/07/16/cassandra-data-modeling-best-practices-part-1/

Comment: i read both part of ebaytechblog then i decide to store actual data in column name using Composite column. But still not come to final conclusion.